# Is it possible to use a Memory Mapped File (C#) instead of a file in command Write_Flash of esptool.py?

Tags: c#, esptool

I have encrypted files which are later decrypted and written to Memory Mapped Files.

I want to write to ESP32's flash a binary file that is decoded into Memory Mapped File. I saw this command in the documentation: `esptool --port /dev/ttyUSB0 write_flash --flash_mode qio --flash_size 32m 0x0 bootloader.bin 0x1000 my_app.bin`
, but I need to insert the data contained in the Memory Mapped File instead of `bootloader.bin` and `my_app.bin`.

Is there a way to send esptool.py the data from the Memory Mapped File other than creating a temporary file and using it as an argument to the command?